# Detect invalid character

Tags: java

I am reading a tab delimited text file (exported from excel) into my java application but it is possible for the file to contain invalid characters that I don't want. For example, in a spreadsheet I have seen these characters show up (I do not  generate the spreadsheet):

```
ï¿½
```

Which when tab delimited show up as:

```
�
```

This is apparently the Unicode Character 'REPLACEMENT CHARACTER'. How do I detect this character in my Java string so I can abort the import?

```
String invalidString = "1234 � test2"
```

Comment: What do you consider to be "valid" characters?

Comment: you can check the ascii values

Comment: @LoganMurphy: Ascii? You mean UTF-8 code points or what?

Comment: yes, the numerical representations of characters, or the characters themselves

Comment: I have updated the question with more information.

Comment: Are those actually invalid characters or just characters that fall outside of your default charset?

Comment: @MxyL they fall outside the charset that makes sense for my application, so they "invalid" for my application.

Comment: @yellavon: Well, what charset makes sense for your application?

Comment: UTF-8 is what I would like to use.

Comment: Do you expect your data to be UTF-8 encoded? Or are you expected to convert the data to UTF-8 yourself before processing it?

Comment: I don't have control over how the file is saved, but I assume it unicode since `�`is the replacement character for illegal UTF-8 `ï¿½`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The answer to this question depends on what you understand as invalid characters.*

## ASCII truncation

A simple check would be to check if the code point lies within a certain range. The lowest printable character is a space. It's decimal value is 32. The highest [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character is `~` with a decimal value of 126. This would truncate it to the range of printable ASCII characters, which is bad for anyone using accents or similar.

## Printability

Another approach is to check whether a character is printable for a certain font. You can use the [`java.awt.Font`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html) class for that. It provides a method [`canDisplay`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#canDisplay%28char%29), which returns if the font has a glyph to display that very character. This could work, but feels really awful. But this *could* be what you want, we can't know.

## Valid letter or number

Another criteria might be if the letter is a valid letter or number. The [`java.lang.Character`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) class provides the method [`isLetter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29) and [`isDigit`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isDigit%28char%29) to determine this.

## Charsets

We all know [TANSTAPT](http://blog.codinghorror.com/there-aint-no-such-thing-as-plain-text/), so you might well have used the wrong charset. Find out if you're using the same charset as Excel.

If these criterias don't fit your intent, you'll have to further specify your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a regex with all your 'valid' characters like :

```
String regexValidCharacters = "[A-Za-z0-9]*";
```

and do something like :

```
if(invalidString.replaceAll(regexValidCharacters, "").length() > 0)
    ABORT!
```

There is probably a better solution but that should work fine.. ^^

Comment: Valid, for a certain input. I consider all characters in `~!"§$%&/öß` printable, yet none of these will pass your regex. The difficulty here is to find the regex to specify all valid characters, as intended by the OP.

Comment: Well my regex was just an example.. i guess you can create one like : `String regexValidCharacters = "[A-Za-z0-9 ~!"§$%&/öß]*";`

Comment: `"[A-Za-z0-9 ~!\"§$%&/öß]*"`   forgot a \

Comment: That is a good example of how easy it is to forget a character. Especially if the set of valid characters is hundreds or thousands of characters.

Comment: Good point. For my current application, I only have one invalid character which is the replacement character for illegal UTF-8 characters.